# Select Image Portion in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to select a small portion of images from the whole image and on clicking that portion, open in full screen. I need such a plugin for Laravel.

I want to upload images of newspaper for archive page. and select a small portion of images so that it will be clickable and will be open in a new tab on clicking that image portion.

Comment: maybe cropper.js is what you are looking for :[ cropper.js](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Map and canvas, with some extended features.

Please visit link below where i have uploaded laravel project for epaper with must of the features that are required for epaper management.

https://github.com/Sabin8peace/epaper

Comment: Yes, I can clip the pdf using this. Thanks.